# EF4 slow association access

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I'm building an ASP.NET 4 web application using EF4 and I have tables like this:

> Product
> Attribute
>
> Product_Attribute_Map

Product_Attribute_Map is a cross table, many to many. So Product can have zero or many Attribute and vice versa.

In code I do this:

```
//Attribute a = new Attribute(); // Edit:
Attribute a = (from a in context.Attributes where a.AttributeID = 1 select a).First();
a.Name = "test"; 
Product.Attributes.Add(a);
```

I noticed a problem which makes this very slow. EF4 will execute this SQL on the server:

```
SELECT 
[Extent2].* FROM  [dbo].[Product_Attribute_Map] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProductID] = [Extent2].[ProductID]
WHERE [Extent1].[AttributeID] = @p1
```

I don't understand why it does this. An Attribute may be assigned to 10.000 Products, which makes this a bad query. It takes over 5 seconds to add an Attribute to a Product...

How can I prevent EF4 from selecting all attributes? And just select the attributes for this product.

Thanks

Edit: This is only using POCO t4 template. EntityObject template doesnt have this problem.

Comment: It looks like EF is trying to populate the `Products` collection on your attribute. What does your table mapping look like?

Comment: Do you have lazy loading turned on? You might not want it here. It won't help the code shown. Try it without.

Comment: Lazy loading is turned on, this is causing the SQL query to execute. If I turn it off, the other existing mappings are removed on a save (because they are not in the collection)

Comment: I feel like the blind leading the blind here (having no EF POCO experience). Do you have Proxy creation enabled?

Comment: Yes, POCO T4 template, lazy loading enabled, proxy enabled. Normal 0..* to 0..* between the tables. I think Ladislav Mrnka perhaps is right and it might have something to do with the association fixup methods. POCO generates clean classes, but it seems to subscribe to the change event of a navigation collection property and do some fixup (to keep in sync, but thats not worth it if its going to select all records from the db...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: This happens because of LazyLoading used together with FixUpCollections generated by POCO template. When you add attribute to product, fixup collection will perform reverse operation as well - it will add prduct to attribute but first access to products collection in attribute will trigger lazy loading and so your query is executed. I don't like fixup collections ... You can modify POCO template to not use them or you can delete Products navigation property in Attribute (if you don't need it).

Comment: Do you know what the drawbacks are of removing the fixup operations?

Comment: @peter: You will lose bidirectional synchronization of relations. Your code doesn't have to be dependent on them. If you add attribute to product and you also want to use reverse direction before you save changes you must manually add product to attribute. You can define your own POCO entities (common in code first) which don't use FixUp collections so it works without them.

Comment: Removing the fixup methods did not fix the problem unfortunately. However your tip on removing the Products navigation property from the Attribute makes it a lot faster. I think i'll keep it this way. But its a mistery to me why the EntityObject T4 does not have this problem.